# Trivial lower bounds for single point mass delta-v problems?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, delta-v

Given two arbitrary elliptic orbits around an ideal single point mass, there will always exist a transfer with the minimal $\Delta v$ required.

It's easy to find an upper bound for this ideal transfer:

$$\Delta v \leq \sqrt{\frac{2}{r_{P1}}} - v_{P1} + \sqrt{\frac{2}{r_{P2}}} - v_{P2}$$

This is a general bi-elliptical transfer, and it's sometimes not possible to do better than that.

It sets a **maximum** $\Delta v$ required for arbitrary transfers. Are there any trivial lower bounds for the **minimal** $\Delta v$ required?

Comment: I'm no expert, but I would've thought the minimum delta V transfer around a non-gravitationally complex single mass in many cases would be your namesake.

Comment: Only for planar, circular orbits.

Comment: You could, perhaps, calculate all possible transfers at a specified interval then iterate through them using an algorithm to decide which is most efficient. That's kind of a cop-out though, I'm sure there's a mathematical way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

While it's a very loose lower bound, it does perhaps have some value to present one most trivial such bound.

---

With basis in the fact that under no circumstances there exists any more efficient way to increase apoapsis than a prograde burn at periapsis, the following bound exists:

$$\Delta v \geq \sqrt{\frac{2}{r_{P1}} - \frac{2}{r_{P1} + r_{A2}}} - \sqrt{\frac{2}{r_{P1}} - \frac{2}{r_{P1} + r_{A1}}}$$

(a simple vis-viva calculation)

Assuming $r_{A2} \geq r_{A1}$, which can be assumed without any loss of generality since the orbits could otherwise be swapped.

Inclination and argument of periapsis obviously add some non-zero cost on top of this, but it's nevertheless a lower bound.

Comment: Isn't the lower bound 0 (or infimum, if I got my nomenclature right), as "two arbitrary elliptic orbits" can be two co-planar elliptical orbits with the same orbital parameters expect e.g. infinitesimally small difference in $r_A$? I.e.: $\inf{\Delta v}_{r_{A_2} \to r_{A_1}} = 0$ Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Ludo What you are missing is that the problem is really "two arbitrary orbits, given their parameters", not "two arbitrary orbits". Your example can be used as a sanity check for any bound, since plugging in the values should yield 0 in that case.

Comment: Oh, you're looking for a lower bound as function of all the orbital parameters, not just a numeric answer. Interesting question, wish I had seen it before.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm looking for. A function would be a nice way to think about it. (And this question is not resolved yet, by far)

Comment: I'll put my thinking hat on. I was really into optimisation etc. in university, but that was 15 years ago. I might be a bit rusty...